# Using raw residuals rather than standardized residuals for Q-Q/P-P plot and residual vs fitted plot

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, residuals, assumptions

When I was doing my undergraduate studies, I remembered that my lecturers usually uses raw residuals to obtain the plots mentioned above. Some books that I have also used raw residuals. However, recently I've read that some authors recommend using standardized residuals. What are the drawbacks of using raw residuals instead if standardized residuals to obtain Q-Q/P-P plot and residual vs fitted plot in order to check assumptions for multiple regression?